# ptr_fun - can't create a type?

Tags: c++, functor

How can i do some thing like:

```
#include <functional>

#include <boost/functional.hpp>

int foo(int){return 1;};

template<typename T>
int bar(T t)
{
  return 10;/*or something*/
}

int main() {

  bar<   std::ptr_fun<int, int>(foo) > (1);
  bar< boost::ptr_fun<int, int>(foo) > (1);

  return 0;
}
```

In both ptr_fun-lines i got `error C2974: 'bar' : invalid template argument for 'T', type expected`. As far as i know `prt_fun` creates a type, but `std::ptr_fun<int, int>(foo)` creates an object.
Is there way to create a type "initialized" with function pointer usinf as much std as possible?

Probably could solve this by manualy coding an functor, but i belive there is the ptr_fun-way.

Comment: You can't "initialize" a type. I don't understand what you would want `T` to be in your examples. Should it be `int`? Or the type `pointer-to-non-const-function-that-takes-an-int-and-returns-an-int`?

Comment: ``bar`` is just an example, it's not "real" code. I need to initialize a template function (bar) with another functions, which will do different job. So, as far as i know, i need to conver the functions to type. This is what ptr_fun do...

Comment: No, `ptr_fun` doesn't "return a type".It returns an object of [pointer_to_unary_function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/pointer_to_unary_function)

Comment: @jrok: make that an answer. Perhaps `bar<pointer_to_unary_function<int,int> >` is close to what the questioner really wants. Although `1` would not be a valid argument, so there's still some mystery left as to what this question means ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptr_fun` returns an object of type [pointer_to_unary_function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/pointer_to_unary_function). You declared your template to take a type parameter, so passing it an object clearly won't work.

You could make it work like this (note you don't need to specify the template parameter, it can be deduced by the compiler):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int foo(int i)
{
    return i;
}

template<typename TResult, typename TArg>
int bar(std::pointer_to_unary_function<TArg, TResult> p, TArg arg)
{
    return p(arg);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << bar(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(foo), 42);
}
```

But you don't really need `ptr_fun`. You could simply do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int foo(int i)
{
    return i;
}

template<typename TFunc, typename TArg>
int bar(TFunc f, TArg arg)
{
    return f(arg);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << bar(foo, 42);
}
```

Or, to make it work like you set it up:

```
int foo(int i) { return i; }

template<typename T>
int bar(T t)
{
    t(42);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << bar( std::ptr_fun<int, int>(foo) );
}
```

Lots of quesswork, becase it's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for good explanation, now `ptr_fun` looks more clear for me.